# How to select multiple distinct data from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my table and I want to select the records having unique id1 and minimum difference, I have already tried this:

```
select * from table group by (id1) having min(difference)
```

but this returns only one record

```
| ID1 | ID2 | DIFFERENCE |
|-----|-----|------------|
|   1 |   1 |          1 |
|   1 |   2 |          3 |
|   1 |   3 |          4 |
|   2 |   1 |          3 |
|   2 |   3 |          4 |
```

Now I want to select the records having minimum difference i.e I want first row and 4th row from table because both having minimum difference and different id1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using sub-query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM Table1 t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT ID1, MIN(difference) AS MinDif
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY ID1
) t2
ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
AND t1.difference = t2.MinDif;
```

If you want to select only `ID1` and `Difference` columns then you can do this even without using sub-query:

```
SELECT ID1, MIN(difference) AS MinDif
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID1
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06e49/8)

Comment: this is returning  same id1,s having min difference for more than one time which is dont need actualy,i want a record that if id2 comes with a particular id1,then these two id never be repeated again in any other record.keeping the min differnce check in mind

Comment: @umairyasin - Just use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate rows. I have updated the answer with `DISTINCT` keyword. Also verify the query in the SQLFiddle.

Comment: ? In which case rows 2 & 4 would, in effect, appear to be identical!?!

Comment: @Strawberry - From the question: *the records having unique id1 and minimum difference*. Also *i.e I want first row and 4th row from table because both having minimum difference and different id1*. So OP doesn't want to unique id2. He only wants unique id1. :)